# Uniy3D - Rescale GameObject with different screen sizes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on a Android game,2D platformer, but currently, I made the game to work only with 3:4 screens. I want to rescale all GameObjects at once and i wonder if it is okey to put all GameObjects inside an empty one and then rescale the empty GameObject. Would it be a good idea?

Also I'm currently rescalling all the game objects one-by-one and It seems to work, but i don't think it's the most practical idea.

I would appriciate it if you have any other suggestians.

Here is my code for now, it is isnide my GameManager script.

```
 `void Start()
  {
      //Getting the screen aspect
      float aspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;

      //Main aspect is 3:4 or 0.75f
      //Getting the new Scale on X and Y for GameObject 1, 2 and 3
      platformScaleX = (aspect * platformMainScaleX) / mainAspect
      trapsScaleX = (aspect * platformMainScaleX) / mainAspect;
      trapsScaleY = (aspect * platformMainScaleX) / mainAspect;

      //Getting the new position of the GameObject on X for the GameObjects 
      //that are on left and right because i want to move them to the 
      //center.
      trapsXleft = (aspect * platformMainPositionX) / mainAspect;
      trapsXright = (aspect * platformMainPositionX) / mainAspect;

      //Applying the new Scale on X for GameObject1
      platforms.transform.localScale = new Vector3(platformX, 1f, 1f);

      //Applying the new Scale on X and Y for GameObject 2 and 3
      leftTraps.transform.localScale = new Vector3(trapsScaleX, 
      trapsScaleY);
      rightTraps.transform.localScale = new Vector3(trapsScaleX, 
      trapsScaleY);

      //Setting the new position of GameObject 2 and 3
      leftTraps.transform.position = new Vector3(trapsXleft, 2.35f, -0.5f);
      rightTraps.transform.position = new Vector3(trapsXright, 4.36f, 
     -0.5f);
 }`
```

Comment: [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/618058/mobile-device-screen-sizes.html) might be useful.

Comment: There is a way that I posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51879361/10223668) link. It might help you.

Comment: Generally you'd change the camera and re-fit any UI.  I wouldn't normally rescale the entire game.